# Unable to change date format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, formatting, format

I have a column of dates with this format (19960124) for instance, and I want to change it to this format (yyyy-MM-dd) on Excel.

I tried all the date formates in Excel, but it gives me #################..etc. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Unix epoch timestamp into a human readable date/time in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164237/how-do-i-convert-a-unix-epoch-timestamp-into-a-human-readable-date-time-in-excel)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no this is something totally different. 
In the Excel toolbar, in the Numbers section, the "Short Date", "Long Date", and "Time" selections are like this #############. 
So when I try to change to any format it gives me just ########.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, just changing the format is not good enough.

If you use a Custom Format of:
***0000-00-00***
 you get:

[image]

But this is not a true date.  You need a formula to convert it into a date.

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date string is in A2, then try this...

In B2

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2))
```

And you can then format the formula column with the desired date format.
You can use the Text function to change the date format in the formula itself, but then the date would be considered as a text string not a real date.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens that Excel refuses the Cell Format command, to get rid from that better use Text command,

=Text(A1, "yyyy - mm-dd")

Drag if required.

ONE more simple example,,

=IF(A3="India",TEXT(C3*53.55,"Rs. #,##0.00"),IF(A3="U.K.",TEXT(C3*0.66,"£ #,##0.00"),IF(A3="Japan",TEXT(C3*99.5,"¥ #,##0.00"),C3)))

Comment: It's my pleasure, please keep asking ☺